# Browser access token storage for multi-domain APIs

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, microservices, access-token

I have run into a bit of a sticky situation with a Single Page App I am working on.

The SPA currently uses JWT tokens to access a couple of stateless (sessionless) API backends, on two different domains.

A typical (simplified) example of the normal user flow would be:

1. User loads 'spa.com' and downloads the SPA app.
2. The User Supplies the Username/Password to the SPA, which makes an API request to 'api.spa.com/auth'
3. This endpoint returns a signed JWT to the SPA which then stores it in localStorage.
4. This JWT is added as a header to any further API requests the SPA makes.
5. The SPA can now access two separate API domains with the same JWT, 'api.spa.com' and 'api.otherdomain.com'
6. As both of these API domains share the JWT secret, they can validate the JWT claims and allow access to their resources.

This works really well, as both separate API servers can validate and respond to requests from the SPA without having to communicate between themselves. However, having done some research on this configuration from a security perspective, it seems that storing access tokens in localStorage is considered insecure, as it is extremely vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Most articles on the subject seem to suggest storing the JWT Access token in an httpOnly, sameSite=strict, CSRF protected cookie. (Examples [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) and [here](https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf))

This would work fine if the SPA only had to access a single domain (the one that set the cookie), but unfortunately, we have two APIS on two domains that need to be accessed.

Nowhere have I seen described a best practice for this situation.

There are a few problems I see with the recommended cookie approach:

- sameSite is not going to work, as both API domains need access to
  the token
- Removing httpOnly (to let the app access the token, to pass to the second API) lets the access token be sniffed via XSS anyway and is no more secure than localStorage.
- The CSRF solution provided by our framework involves encrypting the cookie content by default, and so makes it unreadable via the second API. (The authentication API is written in Rails, but I'm not sure that is pertinent to the underlying issue)

There are some other complex solutions we could look into such as building an API gateway to proxy both APIs under one domain or removing the sameSite requirement, and re-implementing the cookie decryption and anti-CSRF checks on the second API server (this is problematic as the second API is written in nodeJS).

However, I was somewhat hoping there would be a secure solution that would not involve changes as drastic as those mentioned above.

Has anyone run into a similar situation, or could they point me to some best practices for multi-domain access-token authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to store the access token only in browser memory rather than in local storage. You then need to deal with silent token renewal if the user refreshes a page or does multi tab browsing.

I've added some links to blog posts and code samples of mine, with some design patterns that may help you with your own solution. It can be tricky to get SPA security and usability to a level that our stakeholders are happy with.

**SIMPLE CODE SAMPLE**

Token renewal relies on hidden iframe token renewal, which may not work in Safari with default settings, unless persistent SSO cookies are used.

- [Relevant Code - see InMemoryWebStorage](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/13/improved-spa-code-sample-overview/)

**COMPLEX CODE SAMPLE**

If you want to go further, there is a more complex solution referenced in [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/spa-reverse-proxy-based-token-renewal/) which involves:

- Storing the access token in browser memory
- Storing a refresh token in an HTTP only encrypted web domain cookie